# ngShow Won't Update on Click in Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive that opens up row menus on click:

```
app.directive('rowDropdownMenuDirective', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: '@',
            replace: false,
            link: function(scope){
                //close row menus
                scope.menuIndex = -1
                scope.showMenu = function($index){
                    if(scope.menuIndex == $index){
                        scope.menuIndex = -1
                    }else{
                        scope.menuIndex = $index
                    }
                    console.log(scope.menuIndex == $index)
                }
            },
            //templateUrl: 'template.html'
            template: "<div class='options-menu'>" +
            "<a href='#' title='Options' class='options-menu-toggle' ng-class='{openWidgetButton: menuIndex == $index}' " +
            "ng-click='showMenu($index)'>Options</a>" +
            "<ul class='options-menu-widget' ng-show='menuIndex == $index'>" +
                "<li><a href='#'>Approve</a></li>" +
                "<li><a href='#'>Deny</a></li>" +
                "<li><a href='#'>Review</a></li>" +
            "</ul></div>"
        }
    })
```

Once the `scope.showMenu` function is triggered on click, the ngShow is triggered:

`ng-show='menuIndex == $index'`

But whenever the `menuIndex` value is updated in the directive on a separate click event, the value of `menuIndex` in all other directive instances is not updated, and thus ngShow does not update.

EDIT:
`ng-class='{openWidgetButton: menuIndex == $index}'` updates on separate click events, so I am led to believe the issue is specific to ngShow

Comment: I expect to see an ng-repeat because of the $index, but there isn't one in your directive. That feels dangerous... perhaps better to pass the $index into the directive as a parameter rather than suppose an ng-repeat is around it.

Comment: my directive is getting ng-repeat'd 
`<td class="cell-table dt-options" row-dropdown-menu-directive></td>`

Comment: Yep, that's dangerous. Don't know what happens with that ng-repeat and its $index and how that is used in this directive. Seems a dangerous coupling. Ideally, directives should be "plug-and-play", i.e. able to be dropped anywhere without dependency on things elsewhere.

Comment: how might i remedy this situation?

Comment: Try it with a scope.$apply around your scope.menuIndex initializations